# Enabling button on page when file has been chosen in FileUpload component

Tags: javascript, file-upload, asp.net-4.0

I'm using a `FileUpload` component on my ASP.NET 4.0 page, and I also have a button to start the actual upload of the file.

Now it would be really nice if I could have that `Upload` button disabled, until a valid file has been chosen in the `FileUpload` control - but I can't seem to find any way of doing this.

I'm no client-side scripting guru - but I'm wondering if I could possibly hook up some Javascript "voodoo" to detect that a file has been chosen in the `FileUpload` component, and then enable the `Upload` button on the page.

Has anyone done this already? If so: how exactly did you do this? I am stumped and cannot see the forest for the trees...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FileUpload has a `value` property you can use...

```
function ValidateUpload()
{
  var fuData = document.getElementById('fuUploadControl');

  if (fuData.value == '')
  {
       return false;
  }
  else
  {
       document.getElementById('btnSubmit').style.display = "";
  }
  return true;

}
```

I run this function from a [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx) (used to validate my FileUpload control)...
If validation succeeds (e.g. there is a file selected) the button will be shown (it starts invisible by default)

ASPX code:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuUploadControl" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Upload" 
            OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Style="display: none;" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server"   
                     ControlToValidate="fuUploadControl"
                     ClientValidationFunction="ValidateUpload" />
```